# Deploy Nuxt Universal App on AWS Beanstalk 502 Bad Gateway Nginx

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nuxt.js

I try to deploy Nuxt universall app into AWS Beanstalk with Nginx. But it always 502 Bad Gateway. I already deploy including .nuxt folder and add Node Command npm start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I download and see the nodejs.log file. `FATAL  No build files found in /var/app/current/.nuxt/dist/server.` Then I check in the git bitbucket source, the dist directory inside .nuxt is not there.

To solve this make sure to comment the .nuxt and dist in gitignore file.

Comment: THIS IS NOT THE RIGHT ANSWER. Those files should be generated when deploying the application, not commited to version control nor copied to the artifact when building it. Both .nuxt and /dist should be ignored in both .gitignore and .dockerignore files.

Answer (score 1):

AWS EB uses the `.gitignore` file to ignore the files to upload if a `.ebignore` file is not present. Looks like your `.gitignore` has `.nuxt` folder because of which it is not being uploaded to the instances. I would recommend using a `.ebignore` built specifically for AWS EB to configure what needs to be excluded when deploying to EB and **not** including the `.next` folder in it.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Elastic Beanstalk, CodePipeline and Bitbucket.
CodePipeline takes code from Bitbucket once it is pushed and builds in on Elastic Beanstalk.

What helped me is adding to package.json:

```
"deploy": "npm run build && npm run start"
```

and creating Pocfile in root directory of project, content/command of Pocfile triggers the deploy script in package.json file

```
web: npm run deploy
```